# clipped raster but attribute table not updated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, raster-attribute-table

I have a nightlights raster file of India, and I clipped it using the block shapefile for India. After the clipping, the clipped raster files have the attribute of the original raster file. I want the updated attribute tables for the files but I can't figure out the problem. I am attaching a screenshot of the model.

P.S. When I was joining the clip to the green oval using an arrow, a pop-up box appeared where I clicked 'output extent', so that i can check the 'Use input features for clipping geometry' box.[image: model]